# Как грамотно связать c# и Sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Есть код подключения к БД и запрос к ней -

```
SqlConnection SqlConnection;
public async void connectDB()
    {
        string ConnectionAdres = @"Путь";
        SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionAdres);

    await SqlConnection.OpenAsync();

    SqlDataReader SQLDReader = null;

    SqlCommand GetAllEmployCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [employment]", SqlConnection);

    try
    {
        SQLDReader = await GetAllEmployCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        while (await SQLDReader.ReadAsync())
        {
            string test = Convert.ToString(SQLDReader["ID"]) + Convert.ToString(SQLDReader["surname"]) + Convert.ToString(SQLDReader["name"]) + Convert.ToString(SQLDReader["patronymic"]);
         }
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (SQLDReader != null)
        {
                SQLDReader.Close();
        }
   }


 public void closeConnect()
    {
        if (SqlConnection != null && SqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            SqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Как можно разделить подключение и запросы? И нормально если подключение будет открыто на протяжении всё работы программы? Нажимаю на кнопку->с начала вызывается метод подключения, потом запроса. Или писать каждый запрос в коде как у меня это нормальная практика?

Comment: Создавайте подключение каждый раз, как вам надо будет работать с БД. Изобретать пул подключений не стоит, так как он и так есть внутри ADO.NET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В .NET реализован механизим [Connection Pooling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling), который позволяет переиспользовать физическое соединение к базе. Когда вы вызываете `SqlConnection.Open` - вы получаете готовое соединение из пула. Когда вызываете `.Close` - возвращаете его в пул. Поэтому держать объект `SqlConnection` открытым нужно как можно меньше - этим вы позволяете эффективно его переиспользовать. И, заодно, избавляетесь от проблем с обработкой таймаутов неактивности соединения.

По вашему коду - используйте `using` для работы с `SqlConnection` и `SqlDataReader` - он корректно вызовет `Dispose` (`Close`) по завершению работы - т.е. сделает за вас то, что вы сейчас делаете в `try`/`finally`.

Так что если ваш код сократить, получится примерно следующее:

```
public async string SelectTest()
{
    string connectionString = @"Путь";
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

        SqlCommand getAllEmployCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [employment]", sqlConnection);

        using (var reader = await getAllEmployCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        { 
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                string test = Convert.ToString(reader["ID"]) + Convert.ToString(reader["surname"]) + Convert.ToString(reader["name"]) + Convert.ToString(reader["patronymic"]);
                return test; // ?
            }

            return null; // ?
        }
    }
}
```

Но вообще стоит понимать, что ручная работа с ADO.NET - необязательна. Стоит использовать ORM:

- [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), если хотите навороченности
- [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), если хотите простоты

Comment: Если я правильно понял то return test; будет возвращать выборку, а return null, если какая-то ошибка? Как в вашем варианте подучить значение ex(в моём где try/catch)? Как понять что за ошибка?

Comment: А using я подключаю в начале класса, там где все библиотеки. Разве есть разница?

Comment: @xomem это разные using, https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using