# Трудности работы с SQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Написал класс для работы с БД SQL, но с ней у меня возникают некоторые трудности.

1. Отваливается соединение `sqlConnection`, когда вызываю второй раз метод `getState` (работа останавливается и пишет типа "ждём открытия соединения sqlConnection"). Эту проблему можно решить, если везде каждый раз создавать новое соединение
2. Запутался с async await методами.. Я хочу вызывать методы `getState` и `Insert` из любой части программы, но так, что бы это не стопорило остальную работу приложения

В саму БД помещаю статистику сообщений пользователей, при этом сообщения могут поступать и по 100, и по 500 раз в секунду, поэтому хочу максимально оптимизировать работу этого класса.

Естественно, в этих БД я не бум-бум, и всё писал тупо по гайду (кроме методов проверки и создания новой таблицы).

Прошу помочь разобраться с оптимизацией моего класса, либо кинуть какой-нибудь пример того, как правильно должна выглядеть работа с БД.

```
static class SQL {
    public class State {
        public State(string name, string lastMessage, int messageCount, int messageLetterCount) {
            this.name = name; this.lastMessage = lastMessage; this.messageCount = messageCount; this.messageLetterCount = messageLetterCount;
        }
        public string name, lastMessage;
        public int messageCount, messageLetterCount;
    }

    static string connectionString = @"Data Source=blablabla";
    static SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;

    static void Open() {
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();
    }
    public static async void Insert(string name, string message, string channel) {
        if (sqlConnection == null) Open();
        if (!IsCreatedTable(channel)) createTeble(channel);

        int messageCountNew = 0, messageCountLetterNew = 0;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($@"update [{channel.ToLower()}]
                                            set 
                                            [LastMessage] = @LastMessage,
                                            [MessageCount] = @MessageCount,
                                            [MessageLetterCount] = @MessageLetterCount
                                            where [Name] = @Name;
                                            if @@rowcount = 0
                                                insert into [{channel.ToLower()}] (Name, LastMessage, MessageCount, MessageLetterCount)
                                                values (@Name, @LastMessage, @MessageCount, @MessageLetterCount);", sqlConnection);

        State state = getState(name, channel);
        if (state != null) {
            messageCountNew += state.messageCount;
            messageCountLetterNew += state.messageLetterCount;
        }

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", name.ToLower());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastMessage", message);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MessageCount", messageCountNew + 1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MessageLetterCount", messageCountLetterNew + message.Length);

        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
    public static State getState(string name, string channel) {
        if (sqlConnection == null) Open();
        if (!IsCreatedTable(channel)) return null;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM [{channel.ToLower()}] WHERE [Name] = @Name", sqlConnection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", name.ToLower());

        SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        State state = null;
        try {
            dataReader.Read();
            state = new State(name, 
                                Convert.ToString(dataReader["LastMessage"]),
                                Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["MessageCount"]),
                                Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["MessageLetterCount"]));
        } catch {

        } finally {
            dataReader.Close();
        }
        return state;
    }
    private static bool IsCreatedTable(string name) {
        if (sqlConnection == null) Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE (TABLE_NAME = '{name.ToLower()}')", sqlConnection);

        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        return (int)result == 1;
    }
    private static bool IsCreatedUserInTable(string name) {
        if (sqlConnection == null) Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE (TABLE_NAME = '{name.ToLower()}')", sqlConnection);

        return (int)command.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
    }
    private static void createTeble(string channel) {
        if (sqlConnection == null) Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($@"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[{channel.ToLower()}]
                                            ([Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
                                            [LastMessage] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
                                            [MessageCount] INT NOT NULL, 
                                            [MessageLetterCount] INT NOT NULL)", sqlConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: SqlConnection - это короткоживущая одноразовая обертка над реальным соединением. Не делайте ее статической,  создавайте на время одной операции,  и оберните в using, чтобы сразу же выбросить.

Comment: я закрою как дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765714/ - там есть подробный ответ. по второй части - сейчас у вас явно проблемы с работой из-за статического sql connection, перепишите короткоживущие инстансы класса, добейтесь стабильной работы - и задайте новый вопрос именно по async/await с указанием платформы (asp.net / desktop)